# How to align in a row an icon to the end of an edge?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-layout-weight

In my Kotlin Android App project I have Rows with Text and an Icon. The Icon right of Text shall be aligned to the end edge. [image: visible in this example]

The Text has a Modifier with weight(200.0f), but **I do not want to use weight()**. When I remove the `weight()` from text
as in the following the icon comes directly after Text. I tried to align it to CenterEnd - in vain.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

    Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(200.0f)){
        //..
    }
    
    Icon() {
        //
    }
}
```

but I do not want to use `weigth()` so I tried to remove it:

```
Row() {

    Text(){
        //..
    }
    
    Icon(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)) {
        //
    }
}
```

CenterEnd reacts with an error:

> Type mismatch. Required:Alignment.Vertical Found:Alignment

How can I align the icon to the `end` side?

(*Please, instead of discussing why to use weight() or not, I am just looking for alternatives*)

EDIT:

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.SpaceBetween)
```

won't work, since it's **not** recognized in Modifier?! [image]

Comment: Use `modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, true)` in the `Text`

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti I do not want ot use weight() at all

Comment: why? Is there a reason?

Comment: Why don't you want to use weight?

Comment: It's like a Word document. Slightly changing the desings, messes up my view at all. I just do not want to use weight.

Comment: you better explain in details why don't you wanna use `weight`, what unexpected behaviour it produces, and what behaviour do you expect. Without `weight` I only can think of using custom `Layout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using horizontal arrangements = Space Between  in Row
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement

Comment: As commented with screenshot, it is not recognized in Modifer. Strange imports are required!?

Comment: `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween` did work!